# How can I create a JMS topic subscriber for a cluster with multiple server instances in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, jms-topic, subscriber

`I am working to create consumer(or subscriber) on cluster distributed JMS topic. This cluster has 2 server instances in weblogic (A1 and B1 instance). When I am trying to create the subscriber using spring by giving JNDI of the distributed topic. It is not creating the subscription on any instance. However , if I am giving JNDI name of one of the instance , it is able to create the subscription on that instance alone.

Below is the JMS adapter which I am using:

```
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="jmsIn" 
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
        auto-startup="true"
        durable-subscription-name="employeeLoadFactoryDurableSubscription"
        pub-sub-domain="true" 
        subscription-durable="true" 
        message-converter="oxmMessageConverter"
        destination="EmployeeInfoLoadTopic"
        channel="jmsInChannel" 
        error-channel="jmsErrorChannel"
        concurrent-consumers="5"
        max-concurrent-consumers="5"/>
```

Below is the destination topic with specific A1 instance:

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="EmployeeInfoCLoadTopic"
        jndi-name="wls031Sr2A1_JMSServer.EmployeeInfoLoadTopic"/>
```

Below is the connectionFactory configuration:

I tried to change destiantion topic to JNDI name of distirbuted topic not any one instance of it.But it did not help Like :

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="EmployeeInfoCLoadTopic"
    jndi-name="EmployeeInfoLoadTopic"/>
```

Weblogic version - 12.2.1.4